# Dynamic Component creation issue for Material Top Tab Navigator in React Navigation 6

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-navigation

I am using **Material Top Tab Navigator** (React Navigation version 6) in my React Native application.

There are a few dynamic categories. And for each category, a few post listings are there.

I am showing those categories as a tabular format using **Material Top Tab Navigator** and want to get the respective posts upon clicking on a specific Category (or Tab) since those categories are dynamic and directly fetched from an API, so first I am looping through the individual category, something as follows:

```
<PostView.Navigator screenOptions={{ tabBarScrollEnabled: true}}>
     {data.map(category => (
          <PostView.Screen name={category.name} key={category.id}>
              {props =>
                   <Posts {...props} categoryId={category.id} key={category.id}/>
               }
          </PostView.Screen>
      ))}  
</PostView.Navigator>
```

I am able to print the individual category names in their corresponding tabs, and able to get the individual Category ID within a specific tab.

For each Category, I need to call API to get their corresponding Post lists which I am currently doing Within the Posts component, I also have to use a few hooks there i.e useState, useEffect etc. to track pagination and manage posts etc..

My problem is that, when I am going through all of this, I only manage to get the posts from the last category within the Category loop.

E.g. Suppose the categories are Category1, Category2, Category3, .... Category8. When I am looping through those categories I am only able get posts from Category8.

It seems like since I am using a single Posts component for all those categories to show the post lists, it has been overwritten by current category related posts data.

Here is my Posts component structure as follows:

```
const Posts = ({
    categoryId,
}) => {
    const { postDispatch, postState: { data, error, loading } } = useContext(GlobalContext)
    const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1)
    const [refreshing, setRefreshing] = useState(false)
    const [pagination, setPagination] = useState(false)
    const [postData, setPostData] = useState([])
    const [totalPages, setTotalPages] = useState(0)
    const { toggleDrawer, navigate } = useNavigation()

    // const onBrowseLinkClick = webPage => webPage ? WebBrowser.openBrowserAsync(webPage) : ''
    // const onPress = route => route ? navigate(route) : goBack()

    useEffect(() => {
        posts()(postDispatch, categoryId, currentPage)
        if (currentPage > 1 && !pagination) {
            setPagination(true)
        } else if (currentPage == 1) {
            setPagination(false)
        }
        return (() => { })
    }, [currentPage])


    useEffect(() => {
        if (!loading && data?.allPosts) {
            if (currentPage == 1) {
                setNewsData(data.allPosts.data)
            } else {
                setNewsData(postData => [...postData, ...data.allPosts.data])
            }
            
        }
        if (refreshing && !loading) {
            setRefreshing(false)
        }
        return (() => { })
    }, [loading])

    const onEndReached = () => {
        if (currentPage < totalPages && !loading) {
            setCurrentPage(currentPage => currentPage + 1)
        }
    }

    const onRefresh = () => {
        if (currentPage > 1) {
            setRefreshing(true)
            setCurrentPage(1)
        }
    }
    
    return (
        <PostsComponent
            data={postData}
            loading={pagination || refreshing ? false : loading}
            isLoading={loading}
            onEndReached={onEndReached}
            onPress={onPress}
            onRefresh={onRefresh}
            refreshing={refreshing}
            toggleDrawer={toggleDrawer}
            isLoggedIn={true}
            onBrowseLinkClick={onBrowseLinkClick}
        />
    )

}
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using the same component shouldn't result in the mapped components having the same result unless they are sharing the same state that is passed down to them from the parent component or something.

Your issue might be setting the state after fetching the last category and sharing that state with the other screens, but we'll need to see more code if this suggestion doesn't solve your issue.

Comment: I have updated my question. Please have a look into this.